# Delete button when it's clicked javascript

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have some code which is creating a button when a line is added to a chart. When the button is clicked, I want to remove the line from the chart and delete the button. The example can be viewed [here](http://whichchart.com/).

To wit, the code that successfully adds the button is:

```
function getChartData(option){
    var category = $('#category').val();
    var option = option.value;
    var seriesTitle = category+option;
    $.ajax({
        url: "getData.php?action=getChartData",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            category:category,
            option:option
        },
        success: function(json){
            chart.addSeries({
                name: seriesTitle,
                data : []
            });
            $.each(json.Data,function(){   
                chart.series[chart.series.length-1].addPoint([parseFloat(this.Year), parseFloat(this[option])]);
            });
        }

    });
    var series = document.createElement('button');   
    series.onclick = function(){
        removeLine(seriesTitle);
    }
    series.setAttribute('id',seriesTitle);
    series.innerHTML=seriesTitle;
    $('#removeLine').append(series);

}
```

Then when the button is clicked, this code does not do anything:

```
function removeLine(seriesTitle){
    chart.series[seriesTitle].remove();
    $(seriesTitle).remove();
}
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined
removeLine    oil.js:172
series.onclick
```

Bonus points for anyone who knows how I call a particular line in highcharts based on a variable e.g. this works:

```
chart.series[chart.series.length-1].remove();
```

This doesn't:

```
chart.series[seriesTitle].remove();
```

Comment: In inspector `seriesTitle` shows as an object, it looks like you're trying to use it as a string.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed that now, and I think the string is being passed to the removeLine function, but the button is not being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `chart.series[something].remove();` 'something' have to be the serie position as you can see **[here](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#series-object)**. So you have to pass the position thrue the parameter. That's why `chart.series[0].remove();` works.
So if you want to fix this problem you can found the serie position according to the title before remove it, like the following.

```
function removeLine(seriesTitle){
    for(var postion = 0; position < chart.options.series.length; position++) {
        if(chart.options.series[position].name == seriesTitle) {
            chart.options.series[position].remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
function removeLine(seriesTitle){
    $.each(chart.options.series, function(pos, serie){
        if(serie.name == seriesTitle) {
            chart.series[pos].remove();
        }
    });
}
```

To solve the problem when you remove the button you have to do add a hash tag, like the following:

```
$('#' + seriesTitle).remove();
```

**So, your function will be the following:**

```
function removeLine(seriesTitle){
    for(var postion = 0; position < chart.options.series.length; position++) {
        if(chart.options.series[position].name == seriesTitle) {
            chart.options.series[position].remove();
            break;
        }
    }
    $('#' + seriesTitle).remove();
}
```

Comment: Ah, great stuff, the first solution you offered works. Except it should be chart.series[position].name, not chart.options.... Thanks a million. I'll give you the tick in a while, but there's still the issue of removing the button. The seriesTitle is being passed to the removeLine function, but this code $(seriesTitle).remove() isn't removing the button.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the lines

```
        seriesTitle = chart.addSeries({
            name: seriesTitle,
            data : []
        });
```

`seriesTitle` here refers to the the `seriesTitle` created by

```
var seriesTitle = category+option;
```

and overwrites its value. I would guess that `addSeries` is returning an object or `undefined`. `seriesTitle` is passed to `removeLine` with this value, and you're using it as a key to the array `chart.series`.

Try removing the assignment there (it really looks like you don't want it), or just prefix it with var (it will become local to the anonymous function).

---

If you're unsure about the key-value pairs of `chart.series` then pass it to `console.log()` and you can inspect it to see what your keys should look like (and also what the values are).

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the bit about removing the line, and now while I get no error, nothing happens when the button is clicked. E.g. , this does nothing: function removeLine(seriesTitle){$(seriesTitle).remove();} does nothing.